# How do I subscribe a launchpad.net team to all bugs that have a specific tag in a specific project?

Tags: launchpad, tag

I would like to subscribe my team to all bugs that have a certain tag in a certain project.

This should be possible according to:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/151129

But I can't find how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to subscribe to tags in a project:

Firstly, go to the project, where there is a `Subscribe to bug mail` link on the right-hand side.

[image: project with bug subscription link]

Click on that link, and a you can select a team that you belong to
[image]

At the bottom of this, there is an option for restricting the bugs to certain tags.
[image]